# Wrap a request in an array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have such a problem, when I try to send a PayLoad to the server (PUT), I get an error because my object is not in the array **results:[]**

Are there ways to wrap an object inside an array with a specific name?

At the moment my request looks like this:

[image]

The server requires for PUT that the object be wrapped in an array "results:[]", like this:

[image]

```js
  this.service.putNewsData(this.data).subscribe(res => {
    this.service.service.notifySuccess();
    this.ngOnInit();
  }, err => {
    this.service.service.notifyError();
    this.loadComplete = true;
});
```

Where this.data ->

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

I am looking for a way to make it like this ->

```
results: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just looking for wrapping your array in an object:

```
const dataToSend = { results: this.data }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I totally misunderstood your question, you just need to wrap your array in an object like this:

```
this.service.putNewsData({results: this.data}).subscribe(res => {
```